# How to convert date to timestamp in PHP inside array?

Tags: php, arrays, date, timestamp

I have an array just like this:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
           [NO] => 1
           [NO_RINCIAN] => 70
           [TANGGAL_PENARIKAN] => 23-DEC-18
       )
   [1] => Array
       (
           [NO] => 2
           [NO_RINCIAN] => 90
           [TANGGAL_PENARIKAN] => 23-Nov-18
       )
 )
```

What I want to do is to convert `TANGGAL_PENARIKAN` from date to timestamp but in a whole array.

My expected array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
         [NO] => 1
         [NO_RINCIAN] => 70
         [TANGGAL_PENARIKAN] => 1545551313
      )
  [1] => Array
      (
         [NO] => 2
         [NO_RINCIAN] => 90
         [TANGGAL_PENARIKAN] => 1542959313
      )
 )
```

I've tried converting `TANGGAL_PENARIKAN` inside the array, but I didn't know how to combine to be an array again after it.

```
public function getAllData()
{

    $data = $this->model_app->getRincian();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        for ($i=0; $i <= count($value); $i++) { 
            $key = $value['TANGGAL_PENARIKAN'];
        }
        $key = DateTime::createFromFormat("j-M-y", $key);
        print_r(json_encode($key->getTimestamp()));
    }
}
```

> print_r(json_encode($key->getTimestamp()));

Last code above still return :

> 15455513131542959313

Any well thought to advise will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop your array by reference, and modify the column in your loop.

```php
public function getAllData()
{
    $data = $this->model_app->getRincian();
    foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
        $timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat("j-M-y", $value['TANGGAL_PENARIKAN'])->getTimestamp();
        $value['TANGGAL_PENARIKAN'] = $timestamp;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will convert the date into unix timestamp I have used pre defined function `strtotime(String $date)`

```
public function getAllData()
{
    $data = $this->model_app->getRincian();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        for ($i=0; $i <= count($value); $i++) { 
            $key = strtotime($value['TANGGAL_PENARIKAN']);
        }
        $key = DateTime::createFromFormat("j-M-y", $key);
        print_r(json_encode($key->getTimestamp()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, just add & symbol before the value in foreach to modify the original array

```
$array = [
   [
    'no' => 1,
    'NO_RINCIAN' => 70,
    'TANGGAL_PENARIKAN' => '23-DEC-18',
   ],
   [
    'no' => 2,
    'NO_RINCIAN' => 90,
    'TANGGAL_PENARIKAN' => '23-Nov-18',
   ],
];

// notice the & symbol before $value
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("j-M-y", $value['TANGGAL_PENARIKAN']);
   $value['TANGGAL_PENARIKAN'] = $date->getTimestamp();
}

var_dump($array);
```

You can learn more about passing value by reference [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) .

Answer (score 1):

Format of your dates can be used for strtotime function, something as

```
$result = array_map(function($x) { 
        $x['TANGGAL_PENARIKAN'] = strtotime($x['TANGGAL_PENARIKAN']); return $x;},
     $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. It will return perfect timestamp value. It simple and easy..

I think it will help you..

```
<?php
$array = [
   [
    'no' => 1,
    'NO_RINCIAN' => 70,
    'TANGGAL_PENARIKAN' => '23-DEC-18',
   ],
   [
    'no' => 2,
    'NO_RINCIAN' => 90,
    'TANGGAL_PENARIKAN' => '23-JUL-18',
   ],
];
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
   $date_timestamp = strtotime($value['TANGGAL_PENARIKAN']);
   $value['TANGGAL_PENARIKAN'] = $date_timestamp;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
?>
```